# Cant see the default Approver group in SharePoint site

Tags: groups

I am admin to one of my Sharepoint site collection . I have a workflow running on one of the list in my list where my colleague is suppose to approve. If he is busy in his scheduled I should be able to go directly to the workflow and approve the entry.

Though I am able to enter the workflow in the list, the moment i click Approve button I get this error

**Task Update was not accepted
Troubleshoot issue with Windows SharePoint services**

Now on searching the forums I found that even Site collection admin should be added in default approver group of the site to approve request on other behalf. Now the problem comes here, I checked the groups in my site collection and I dont see any Approvers group. Where to find it? or can I just add one group..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sharepoint 2013 the approval group comes with the publishing feature enabled.
If you do not want to enable this then create a new permissions level, give it a name and ensure that approval is ticked as a permission level

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be group permission problems. Just check out your colleague belongs to which group and add your user to that. Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I am already added to members group where my colleague is added. But workflows items are assigned to him for approval. I go on assigning on his behalf only when he is not present. I should be able to do it since I am the Admin as well for this site. But i cant. Solution says admin needs to be in Approver group as well. And here i am stuck..No Approver group in my site